# check file exists or not in folder in php

Tags: php, directory

i want to know how to check the filename in folder with some condition.

for example :
the folder name is "output"
this folder containing the following the images.
2323a.Png
5235v.Jpeg
2323s.jpg
23523s.JPEG
etc..,

if i check the file name is "2323a.png" but there is file name is 2323a.Png.

how to i check the filename is incasesensitive.

thanks in advance

Comment: And what system are you running your script on? On windows `file_exists` is case insensitive so this will be sufficient. On linux file names are case sensitive so 2323a.png and 2323a.Png are two separate files. If you are running your script on linux server and want to use lowercase only file names, you should rename those files first.

Answer (score 1):

Imho you have to read the directory contents

```
function file_exists_ignore_case($path) {
    $dirname = dirname($path);
    $filename = basename($path);
    $dir = dir($dirname);
    while (($file = $dir->read()) !== false) {
        if (strtolower($file) == strtolower($filename)) {
            $dir->close();
            return true;
        }
    }
    $dir->close();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [strtolower](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) on your filenames to check if they exist.

```
if(strtolower($filename) === '2323a.png')
```

Comment: if i check the file name is 2323a.pNg, then what will i do?

Comment: Add a str_replace around the strtolower() function, str_replace('.png', '.pNg', strtolower($filename)). But if you lowercase the filenames this shouldn't be needed because everything will be lowercase.